# Macbook 2010 13 inch keyboard not working untill after boot into os but no os installed

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp

So basically i got this macbook used and when i got it it had windows 7 and no mac os x at all. I tried to install Mac os x from usb but it wouldent boot because the keyboard was not working... then i tried to use transmac to install the mac os x installer onto the internal hdd from a windows 7 desktop and now it says no bootable drive whenever i turn it on. Help me please!

Answer (score 1):

If you hold the **Option** key while booting does anything appear? If not you may have damaged the partition. Since your computer is a 2010 model it is not capable of using Internet Recovery. Your only option would be 1) Call Apple support and ask them to ship you an OS X install DVD (you will have to pay for it) or 2) if the install DVD fails you may have messed up your HDD and may need to buy a new one.

All in all, you will **NEED** to call Apple to buy an OS X Install DVD (unless you have it)

Comment: nothing happens when i hold down option or any other keys...i have a mac os x install disc and it appears there is something wrong with the keyboard itself. however i can not buy a new keyboard at this time. i do have a external usb one if that helps....any ideas?